# SVG variable shows undefined index when converting to PDF using TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, canvas, svg, tcpdf

i have a SVG file.i am trying to download as PDF file using TCPDF. SVG is converting to PDF if there is no `#` in the SVG file.The problem is the file '#'.please suggest me what to do.

**canvas.svg:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1140" height="600" viewBox="0 0 1140 600" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.7.17</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="1140" height="600" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
<g clip-path="url(#clipCircle)">
<image xlink:href="http://localhost/canvas/560.jpg" x="-235" y="-280" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="470" height="560" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="translate(235 280)"></image>
</g>
<clipPath id="clipCircle"><rect x="50" y="120" width="670" height="320" rx="40" ry="40"></rect></clipPath></svg>
```

**pdf.php:**

This is the file which i am using to download the file as PDF.

```
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 10, true);
// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();



$pdf->ImageSVG($file='images/canvas.svg', $x=30, $y=100, $w='', $h=100, $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false);


//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('canvasoutput.pdf', 'D');
```

Error:

Notice: Undefined index: clipCircle in D:\xampp\htdocs\canvas\TCPDF\tcpdf.php on line 23043

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\canvas\TCPDF\tcpdf.php on line 23044
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The svg file works in the web page but did not when i convert to PDF.I have found the problem. Actually `clipPath` should be enclosed in `defs`. This is the preferred solution.it works in TCPDF also.

**canvas.svg:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1140" height="600" viewBox="0 0 1140 600" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.7.17</desc>
<defs>
//added Here
<clipPath id="clipCircle"><rect x="50" y="120" width="670" height="320" rx="40" ry="40"></rect></clipPath>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="1140" height="600" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
<g clip-path="url(#clipCircle)">
<image xlink:href="http://localhost/canvas/560.jpg" x="-235" y="-280" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="470" height="560" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="translate(235 280)"></image>
</g>
</svg>
```